# Bash Scripting for OpenShift - Unreadable ( || , [ -f pidfile] )

Tags: bash, shell, openshift

I've done all of my learning in Ruby, and am now delving into the depths of Bash scripting for OpenShift.  It is far less obvious what each command is doing....

Could someone explain to me what the following does:

```
[ -f ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}redis.pid ] || ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}redis/bin/redis-server ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}redis/bin/redis.conf
```

The second part is obviously running the `redis-server` binary with the `redis.conf` configuration.  However I'm not sure what the `||` accomplishes, or the `[ -f $SOME_PID_FILE ]`

Help appreciated!

Comment: From what I remember, `[ -f ... ]` checks to see if the file exists. The `||` is an OR, so this code starts the Redis server if an existing process isn't already running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `redis-server` creates a file called `redis.pid` upon launch and deletes this file when exiting. The first condition checks if the server is running by testing the existence of this file with the `-f` test option, which means if file exists. In case `[ -f $SOME_PID_FILE ]` is wrong, meaning the server is not running, the `||` (or) operator will execute the right hand side, i.e., it will launch the server.

So this statement means:

```
if the server is not running
    run the server
```

Comment: Thanks !!  Is isn't totally different than ruby then :)